# на iphone падает скрипт при форматировании с помощью Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, iphone

iphone под сафари и хромом не может обработать данный код. Под андроидом и на ПК все работает. Дата в data[i].DateTime в виде строки типа "2018-08-30 10:00:00.000". В код вставляется как:

```
<div id="datef">10:00<br>30.08.2018</div>
```

Как можно обойти это?

```
  var formatterD = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ru", {
       year: "numeric",
       month: "numeric",
       day: "numeric"
  });
  var formatterT = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ru", {
       hour: "numeric",
       minute: "numeric"
  });

  ddt = new Date((Date.parse(data[i].DateTime)));
  $('#datef').html(formatterT.format(ddt)+'<br>'+formatterD.format(ddt));
```

Comment: Добавьте вывод ошибки. Чтобы увидеть ошибку на телефоне, вы можете завернуть проблемный код в `try { your code here} catch (error) {alert(error)}`

Comment: Попробовал исключать разные блоки. Ошибка выходит на вызове formatterT.format(ddt). RangeError: date value is not finite in datetimeformat format()

Comment: Пришлось добавлять T и зону "2018-09-13T08:18:14.010+05:00". Яблочные поделия не переваривают стандарты в полном объеме. Надкусанное сказывается, похоже. Не понятно только, это от системы  идет, если и хром на них себя так же ведет или что-то другое.